# Viewing html in Gitweb

Tags: html, git, browser, tree, gitweb

via its **tree** view Gitweb is a great tool to browse through repository content at filesystem level. In case there are files inside the repository it's then easily possible to simply view/open them with your browser - just click them. Problem is if these are "html" files referencing other resources (pictures, javascript, etc.) a browser can't find them because although they are available in the repository, and also accessible via Gitweb's "tree" view - they aren't served at there expected location by the (Git)web server.

Stupid question: Is it any possible to configure Gitweb to do some sort of magic URL rewriting or whatever else to be able to fully view an html file with all its references in case the html file itself and all referenced content is present?

I actually don't think so.

Current work-around: At the moment I just `clone/check-out` the git repository into a directory served by a web server. Works, but whenever anyone wants to view an older commit-level I have to checkout another `commit-id`. The flexibility of just browsing through files AND commit levels is gone. Plus whoever wants to use this work-around must be able to use git. Also people must know another URL to actually see the content from the repository.

Question: Does anyone see a more flexible work-around?